# Fit image in html to screen size with absolute pixel values

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to place an arbitrary sized image inside a html file. This file will be consumed by a program to generate a (hopefully) one page pdf. The problem arises when specifying relative style values like `style="max-width:99%;max-height:99%;"` . This looks great in html, but confuses the heck out of my other script that takes care of generating the pdf.

If i leave it without messing with the style too much the script cuts off chunks of it which again is a big no-no

On the other hand , stuff like `style="width:500px;height:500px;"` seems to work great with it. So the way i figured it out i have to

- get the image size and figure the orientation from that (landscape or portrait)
- figure out the optimum absolute height and width for the new image and punch that into the html
- make a prayer to the dark gods of wkhtmltopdf and hope i get a valid file instead of a blank page

So i guess the question would resume to what would be some good absolute values for width and height in order for the image to fit the screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try calling something like [this](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#8dd7897e3b14008ae38cd2954da5717d)? (a resize in js)

Comment: This is supposed to be a pure html operation, no JS involved, since i'll be getting the image and call the conversion script inside a java program.

Comment: Try setting `display:block;` and remove `max-` leaving just `width:99%;height:99%;`.

Comment: That works for when the image is larger that the screen size, but has the side effect of enlarging otherwise smaller images to fit all screen. So i still have to figure out of threshold of switching the style from percentage to absolute

Comment: I can't be much help without seeing the code. Can you make a snippet?

Comment: you could have one css file for web and one for print. That way you can set the styles in each you no will work. You can do this by passing `--print-media-type` in the `wkhtmltopdf` call.